# How do I loop through a column of values?

Tags: r, function, loops

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name <- c("orange", "apple", "watermelon", "lemon", "lime")
order <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
keywords_list <- data.frame(Name, order)
```

I want to loop through the order. So, file 1 would have the results for orange, file 2 would have results for apple, file 3 would have results for watermelon and lemon, and file 4 would have results for lime.

```
for (i in unique(keywords_list$order)){
  
    keywords_list <- keywords_list %>%
      filter(order == i)
    
  keywords_vector <- keywords_list %>% pull(Name)
  
  result_full <- lapply(keywords_vector, function(x) gtrends(x, geo = "US", time = "2004-08-04 2004-11-02", onlyInterest = TRUE))
  
  result_full_df <- ldply(result_full, data.frame)
    
    write.csv(result_full_df, paste0("file_",i,"csv"))
  }
```

Currently, the code is only outputting file_1.csv with the results for orange. It outputs file 2, 3, and 4 but there's nothing inside. Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Comment: for loop read objects in the environment. after the first loop, you have altered the keywords_list from one that contain 4 orders, into just 1 orange. Subsequently on i = 2, 3, 4, the keywords_list is further altered to dataframe with no value. Good practice would be to put in different name. Consider writing function instead.

Comment: @AdamQuek So I'll have something like: `for (i in 1:nrow(keywords_list2)){
  
    keywords_list2 <- keywords_list %>%
      filter(order == i)
    
  keywords_vector <- keywords_list2 %>% pull(Name)`

Comment: Something like that. Or you can just do `split(keywords_list, keywords_list$order)` and word with the list.